# dateFromString working in ios 6 but not in ios 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6, nsdate

This code working on iOS 6.0 simulator, but not working on iOS 5.0

```
NSString *unformattedDate = @"2008-09-25T20:41:11.000+00:00";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:unformattedDate];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yy"];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString]);
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: Try and remove the `:` from the `unformattedDate`

Comment: check your device date format

Comment: iOS 5 doesn't support `ZZZZZ` for a timezone format. That was added in iOS 6 (actually it was added to a newer version of the Unicode spec for date formatting which didn't exist in iOS 5).

Comment: @rckoenes Your method works :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `ZZZZZ` date format specifier was added in iOS 6, you can't format dates that have a timezone in the `+99:99` format with iOS 5. Both versions do support the `+9999` format using `ZZZZ`. If you know that your date/time strings will always have a timezone with the colon, then you can strip the colon.

```
NSString *unformattedDate = @"2008-09-25T20:41:11.000+00:00";
NSRange range = [unformattedDate rangeOfString:@":" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
if (range.location != NSNotFound && range.location >= unformattedDate.length - 4) {
    unformattedDate = [unformattedDate stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
}
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *posix = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:unformattedDate];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yy"];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString]);
```

Note that with fixed formats like this, you must set the formatter's locale to the special "en_US_POSIX" locale.