# iOS 6: Conversion from NSString to NSDate not working

Tags: objective-c, ios6, nsdate

`date` is always nil, and I am not able to understand what the issue is.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2013-07-16T07:40:36.939-04:00"];
```

Comment: That code looks good to me.  How are you verifying `date == nil`?

Comment: what this indicates "-04:00" ?

Comment: @sagarcool89 "Zone"; see: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: I think you should remove ':' from '-04:00'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting an ISO 8601 timestamp into an NSDate: How does one deal with the UTC time offset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185230/converting-an-iso-8601-timestamp-into-an-nsdate-how-does-one-deal-with-the-utc) - See joel.d's answer.

Comment: See also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15415127/1187415 which explains the differences between iOS 5 and 6.

Comment: @Fogmeister What's the error then?

Comment: @Fogmeister Well I've had a go and didn't find anything too obvious (I suspect it might need `ZZZZZZ` in the format string).  Perhaps you can find the exact answer if it's *that* obvious...

Comment: @trojanfoe given that there are maybe 4 or 5 questions asking how do you convert X date format into NSDate a bit of searching will find the answer. I have needed to find this answer myself in the past. However, now I don't need to find it. I suggest the OP should probably do a search (either on Google) or SO. They both come up with SO answers fairly well. That way he'll find the solution without having to ask yet another NSString -> NSDate question.

Comment: @Fogmeister That's hardly the same as your original claim that this was "exactly the same as every other string/date conversion question ever asked on SO", is it?

Comment: @trojanfoe "That's hardly the same as" what I actually wrote which was "possible duplicate of every other nsstring to nsdate question...". Please don't misquote me back to myself.

Comment: @Fogmeister I was paraphrasing as you deleted your comments and I couldn't find them again.  I didn't take your comments out of context though did I?

Comment: @trojanfoe paraphrasing with quotes is not paraphrasing. I said "possible duplicate" due to the way that SO adds comments when you vote to close as a duplicate (as the person before me had done) (twice). Nor did I ever say that it was "that obvious" which you seem to have attributed to me too. I think we're getting slightly off topic now. If you so desperately want the answer to this (you seem to be interrogating me for it) then please search SO for it.

Comment: it needed ZZZZ instead of Z to get it to work

Comment: #define DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT_TIMESTAMP       @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ"

Comment: Yep, the format `-04:00` for timezone is not recognized by the standard "Z" format.  The relatively new "ZZZZZ" notation is needed.  Or there are several simple ways to remove the offending ":" character so that "Z" will handle it.

Comment: It is being returned from the server, so I would be reluctant to change it unless there is no other work around

Comment: The ":" can be removed by processing the received string -- no need to change the sender.  But the new "ZZZZZ" format is a better choice, in most cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like this,for adding hours use `-` symbol and for substacting use `+` symbol.

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2013-07-16T07:40:36.939-04:00"];//chnage symbal here.
    NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

O/P:-`2013-07-16 11:40:36 +0000`

Comment: @Peyush Goel:once try like this it'l helps you may be.

Comment: As I mentioned.... it worked as soon as I used ZZZZ instead of Z. Only thing troubling me is the timezones it is showing either GMT+5:30 or Indian Standard Time. I want to display IST. zzz should have worked but it isnt working.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this :

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS-hh:mm"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2013-07-16T07:40:36.939-04:00"];
NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

Timezone's are using below formates :

```
     Z
```

±hh:mm  or    ±hhmm

```
    ±hh
```

Let me know if you face any problems..

Comment: date is coming from the server and can't be altered. And I need to convert that timezone to a format so I would need that as well

Answer (score 0):

Since the timestamp from the server is in the format -04:00, I had t use ZZZZ

```
#define DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT_TIMESTAMP @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
NSString* str = @"2012-03-01T23:08:25.000Z";   // NOTE the change is here
NSDate* date = [df dateFromString:str];
```